# How to trace a JS function appeared out of nowhere in one of the Magento 2 category page?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, frontend, jquery, frontend-error

one of the category page of our Magento site throws an JS error `Uncaught ReferenceError: j$ is not defined`. Upon investigating, this was found present with

`<script>
     j$('h1').hide();
</script>`

How and where do I remove j$ from this function. I need to know where this code resides.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search your whole project for `j$('h1').hide()`, your IDE will tell you what file it is from.

If it returns nothing then it isn't in your code base and may be added by a third party.

**Added:** Based on the 'category-description' class it looks like your customer has added this inside the category description field? It'll be worth checking in the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks Ben for this insight. I strongly suspect it is not within the codebase as I repeatedly searched through the whole project. Just want to inform you that our client sometime added this j$ in a custom JS file which was long ago removed from this file.

Comment: Could your customer have added it inside a static block or CMS page? If so you can search the static block and CMS page tables in the database for j$ and it may flag up some results for you.

Comment: Ohh I've just noticed the element it is inside, it looks like the code was added as part of the category description?

Comment: Let me check the category description first since it is unlikely that the client could have added it inside a static/CMS page? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: could you please tell me how to search tables  in the database for j$?

Comment: There are 4 tables with the occurrance of what I am trying to locate. Your advice on checking tables is correct.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ben, kindly have a look at the post on some JS dependencies(.html only) being made to add .js besides .html when CDN is enabled with the advanced JS bundling. Any suggestion/direction/documentation that you refer me to will do me a good deal of help. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316025/magento-2-3-4-enabling-cdn-for-static-subdomain-results-in-some-knockout-js-dep