# How do I create a symlink?

Tags: magento2, frontend, cdn, symlinks, advanced-bundling

We recently setup CDN for the static assets. As an old discussion on the github indicates, advanced JS bundling and CDN don't go together. What is happening is explained below.

require.js is trying to load:

```
https://sdev.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/version1593534261/frontend/Perfectmakeupmirrors/argento-luxury-custom/en_US/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/listing.html.js
```

with an additional `.js` extension instead of

```
https://sdev.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/version1593534261/frontend/Perfectmakeupmirrors/argento-luxury-custom/en_US/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/listing.html
```

since advanced JS bundling and CDN don't work together yet.

I seek help in creating a symlink so that the correct file ending only with `.html` is accessed by the browser.

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, Mukesh. It was fixed. Do you have a solution that might be different from the one I found?

Comment: I do not have a solution. Could you share how did you fix it?